# ReactJS - отправить из одного файла в другой

Tags: reactjs

Никак не могу из одного файла поменять статус в другом, пытался отправлять `<Smallblock terms='1212' />`, но в `console.log(this.props)` не приходит

Вот код:

**send:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Smallblock from './Smallblock';
import '../css/sendpost.css';


class Sendpost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        }
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({text: ""});
        <Smallblock terms='1212' />
    }

    handleTextChange(event) {
        this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {      
        return (
            <div className="form_input">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text' className="inputtext" placeholder="Что у вас нового?" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
                    <button>Send</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sendpost;
```

**Smallblock:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import '../css/smallblock.css';


class Smallblock extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
        alert(this.props);
        this.state = {
            count: "1"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="smallblock">
                <div className="count">{this.state.count}</div>
                <div className="text">Записей</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Smallblock;
```

Answer (score 0):

Так и ничего не будет приходить так как там есть несколько ошибок.

1.Надо `{this.props.terms}` ведь такое свойство стоит у компонента (это не совсем ошибка )

```
 <Smallblock terms='1212' />
```

2.Компонент внутри функции не будет рабочим его надо возвращать и использовать как `JSX` компонент.Я написал его после формы в компоненте `Sendpost`

Полный рабочий код.

Ссылка на [**codesandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/qzlpzzn9o4)

**Sendpost**

```
class Sendpost extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: ""
        }
        this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({text: ""});

    }

    handleTextChange(event) {
        this.setState({text: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {      
        return (
            <div className="form_input">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input type='text' className="inputtext" placeholder="Что у вас нового?" value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
                    <button>Send</button>
                </form>
                <Smallblock terms='1212' />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Sendpost;
```

**Smallblock**

```
class Smallblock extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.terms);
        this.state = {
            count: "1"
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="smallblock">
                <div className="count">{this.state.count}</div>
                <div className="text">Записей</div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```